# String comparison fails for value set/get from jquery html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, comparison

I set the html of a message dialog with `.html(CONSTANT)` and then later check the value of the message dialog with `.html() == CONSTANT`.

Despite the types of both sides of the comparison being confirmed as strings, and the values of the strings being identical, the comparison returns false.

Why?

```
$("#notice").html(MESSAGES['VERIFY_EMAIL']);
...
if($("#notice").html() == MESSAGES['VERIFY_EMAIL']){
  alert('FTML!');
}
```

The debug console confirms the following:

```
$("#notice").html()
-> "Please <span style="color:#982101;">confirm your email!</span>"

typeof($("#notice").html())
-> "string"

MESSAGES['VERIFY_EMAIL']
-> "Please <span style='color:#982101;'>confirm your email!</span>"

typeof(MESSAGES['VERIFY_EMAIL'])
-> "string"

($("#notice").html() == MESSAGES['VERIFY_EMAIL'])
-> false
```

What am I missing about string comparisons in javascript?

Comment: Found it- it's the quotes. `.html(CONSTANT)` replaces the single quote in the style property with double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the `.html()` converts the result to use double quotes.

Use escaped double quotes in `MESSAGES['VERIFY_EMAIL']` to fix:

```
MESSAGES['VERIFY_EMAIL'] = "Please <span style=\"color:#982101;\">confirm your email!</span>";
```

Comment: Thanks for supplying both the cause and resolution for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes in your `.html()` string, but single quotes in the `MESSAGES['VERIFY_EMAIL']` string

Comment: Yep- `.html(CONSTANT)` apparently substitutes double quotes for single ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think because $("#notice").html() returns span style attribute wrapped in double quotes, but your comparison string's style attribute is wrapped in single quotes.